# Conditional remove duplicate in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a dataset where I want to remove duplicates in column H for each corresponding unique value in column I. For example, in the screenshot in the link, if I just remove duplicate in column H there would only be 1 row left. However, I need to preserve both unique values in column I. Note that I cannot just remove duplicates in column I because I am not looking for unique values in column I by itself, but rather all applicable column I values in relation to each distinct column H value. How can I do this?

[Example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCu8Y.png)

Comment: You mean to say after you remove duplicates in Column H `10728051` & in Column I `15.39785 nd 24.85653` should remain !! ☺

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. From your public data I see that you have not yet visited the [tour]. Please do so, and read it to the end, it only takes a minute. Also familiarize yourself with the [help], especially regarding [asking](https://superuser.com/help/asking).

Comment: Is my understanding correct, that if moving from top downwards, and inspecting one row (current row) at a time, you want to delete the current row, if both **H and I** columns hold values that already exist in a previous row?

Comment: Rajesh S - Yes, that is what I mean. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Tom Brunberg - actually I only want to delete the current row if H column hold values that already exist in the previous row, EXCEPT if there are multiply I column values that correspond to the same H column value. In these exceptional cases, I want all the unique I column values that correspond to that same H column value to remain. Hope that clears things up?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've understood,

- Columns <s>G,</s> **H & I** are interdependent on each other to set a row as unique in your data set.
- Therefore our criteria for a unique row of data is;

  - **each row** in your data set only **requires 1 unique value in** either <s>Column G and/or</s> **Column H and/or Column I** to set itself as unique to all other rows.

**How to remove duplicates that do not meet the above criteria**

1. Highlight your table
2. In DATA Tab click on Remove Duplicates
3. Click on 'Unselect All'
4. Check 'My data has headers'
5. Scroll down select your important headers <s>'G',</s> **'H' & 'I'**
6. Click Ok

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my original question which may have confused things. I have edited the question to clear up - I am only concerned about columns H and I, not G. Also, my comment in response to Tom Brunberg's comment may help clarify things as well. Thanks!

Comment: Just select headers H & I then, from the 9 rows of data you posted in the snippet only 2 rows are unique based on column H & I, your question needs some more work.